# ArcGIS Portal - Click to add a marker and get coordinates

Tags: arcgis-online, web-mapping, arcgis-portal

How would this be best approached in ArcGIS Online and/or Portal?

A user needs to click a point on a web map to identify a work location.

Clicking the map adds a marker and also stores the XY coordinates in a variable to send to a external apps, databases and files.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the short [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you check out Workforce for ArcGIS.

Workforce for ArcGIS has a workflow for creating assignments that pretty much follows your need - Open Workforce Project -> Add Assignments -> Click on Map. Then you fill out the info on that assignment and assign it to a worker which would have the mobile workforce app installed and they could see their assignments. These assignments are in a hosted feature layer and can be exported out in any format you need. You could also do this setup with enterprise https://doc.arcgis.com/en/workforce/android-phone/help/workforce-enterprise-support.htm